# What does a view controller do for me when orientation changed?

Tags: iphone

A simple iphone program generated by project template View-based Application, with several buttons, and I added following code:

```
- (void) showInfo: (UIView *) view {
    NSLog(@"view bounds  %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f", view.bounds.origin.x, view.bounds.origin.y, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"view frame   %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f", view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"view center  %6.2f %6.2f", view.center.x, view.center.y);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval) duration {
    switch(toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            [self showInfo: self.view];
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            [self showInfo: self.view];
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [self showInfo: self.view];
            break;
    }
}

- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) fromInterfaceOrientation {
    switch(fromInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            [self showInfo: self.view];
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            [self showInfo: self.view];
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [self showInfo: self.view];
            break;
    }
}
```

Launch simulator in Portrait, change to landscape right. I can get:

view bounds    0.00   0.00 320.00 460.00
view frame     0.00  20.00 320.00 460.00
view center  160.00 250.00
In portrait, view's size is 320x460, and it's origin is (0,20) because of status bar.

view bounds    0.00   0.00 480.00 300.00
view frame     0.00   0.00 300.00 480.00
view center  150.00 240.00
In landscape right, bounds' size is changed to 480x300, However, the origin of the frame is (0, 0). And the size of frame is different from bounds.

In my head, I imagine that these coordinates are like following pictures:

[image: Portrait]

[image: Portrait]

My question is: in landscape right, it seems that the frame's origin points to one location while bounds' origin points to a different one. So I think somewhere in a view controller some rotation happens. Where is it and what does it do?

Thanks for reading this long and not-so-clear question. :)

Comment: In apple's doc, View Controller Programming Guide for iOS, in section Responding to Orientation Changes in One Step, it says: #

The window adjusts the bounds of the view controller’s view.

This causes each view in the view hierarchy to be resized based on its autoresizing mask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In landscape mode, the "content view" (`controller.view`) will be resized and applied a transform of 90 degrees.

Since `bounds` represent the bounding rectangle in the *internal* coordinates system, the `bounds.origin` will always at the upper-left corner of the view itself.

However, `frame` is the bounding rectangle in the *external*, or parent, coordinates system. The parent of your view is the window, which still has the origin in the device's absolute upper-left corner. Hence your `frame.origin` is at that position in landscape mode.

Comment: Thanks. Where do resizing and 90-dgree transform happpen? In view controller?

Comment: @yehnan: In some will-never-be-documented procedures in `UIWindow`.

Comment: This was a much better summary of frames vs. bounds than is offered by Apple's own class documentation. I was failing to understand why the height and width of the frame were not with respect to the device's orientation until I read KennyTM's post. (And as a result, I learned that I want to generally stick to laying out subviews in relation to the bounds, as opposed to the frame, of their parent.)