# iPad's orientation not working when I use its view's bounds property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

My iPad app is in Portrait when I set its iPad orientation property to landscape its view's bounds doesn't change it takes `768 x 1024` size.

Here my problem is view's bounds not change when I change my orientation.

Here is my code:

```
if(self.hidden || hiding || !view.superview) {
    UIWindow *viewWindow=[[UIWindow alloc]init]; 

    if([self isPad]){
        viewWindow = forView.window;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CustomKeyboardWillShowNotification object:self];

// remove from old view and add to new view (if necessary)
if(view.superview && (view.superview != viewWindow)) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
if(!view.superview) {

         CGFloat x;
         if([self isPad]){
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 198)];
            NSLog(@"view frame=%@",view);
            x = view.bounds.size.width /2;

            NSLog(@"x=%f",x);

        }else
        {
             x = view.bounds.size.width / 2;
        }

        //CGFloat y = viewWindow.frame.size.height + (view.frame.size.height / 2);
        CGFloat y;
        if([self isPad]){

             y = viewWindow.frame.size.height/1.3 + (view.frame.size.height);
             NSLog(@"y=%f",y);

        }else{
            y = viewWindow.frame.size.height + (view.frame.size.height / 2);
        }
   //self.hiddenCenter = CGPointMake(x, y);
   self.hiddenCenter = CGPointMake(x, y);
   view.center = hiddenCenter;
```

Comment: Please post your code related to orientation change.

Comment: Also I think you need to just go through answer of this link for your understanding of view bounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152057/what-does-a-view-controller-do-for-me-when-orientation-changed

Comment: What exactly this line does ` NSLog(@"view frame=%@",view);`?

Comment: When does this code execute (i.e. what method is it in, and when is that method called)? At some points in the autorotation process, views haven't been resized yet. Also, if this view is a subview of another, have you set the autoresizing mask on the view (the arrows/springs in the size inspector in IB) such that it will resize?